# Kernel of adjoint and orthogonal complement images

Tags: linear-algebra, inner-products, adjoint-operators

Alright, suppose we are given $V$, a finite dimensional inner product space, and a linear map, $T:V \rightarrow V$, with its corresponding adjoint, $T^\star :V \rightarrow V$. I want to show:

$[im(T)]^\perp = ker(T^\star)$.

However I just, for example, start with the left side and go as this:

$[im(T)]^\perp = \{ v \in V | \langle v,T(x) \rangle=0, \forall x \in V \}$

which I start working on as so:

$= \{ v \in V | \langle v,T(x) \rangle =0, \forall x \in V \}$

$= \{ v \in V | \langle T^\star (v),x \rangle =0, \forall x \in V \}$

But now I get stuck and I really just want to show $T^\star(v)=0$ in my set, but cannot manage to find the logic to get there. Any insight?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Isn't $x$ arbitrary? What can you infer from the properties of the (nondegenerate) inner product?

Comment: So you are suggesting I pick a special $x$ since it must hold true for all $x$s?

Comment: @anakhronizein No, that $x$ need not be $0$, so [$T^\star(v)$ must be](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/InnerProduct.html)...

Comment: I don't quite follow, but letting $x=T^\star (v)$ means that $\langle T^\star (v),T^\star (v) \rangle = 0$ implies $T^\star (v)=0$ by the iff on the 4th axiom on that page...

Comment: @anakhronizein Look at the second paragraph. You're assuming the inner product is nondegenerate, so $T^\star(v)=0$ in your set.

Comment: @anakhronizein Here's a simple analogy. If $x\times y=0$, and $y$ is any arbitrary integer/real number/complex number/..., what must $x$ be?

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post.

Comment: @Sanath Oh. I see now. Thank you.

Comment: @MarkFantini This is a hint, not a clarification (but I understand why it can be misunderstood like a clarification).