# Proof of "$\operatorname{Im}A^*$ equals orthogonal complement of $\operatorname{Ker}A$"

Tags: linear-algebra, proof-verification, inner-products, orthogonality, adjoint-operators

Consider the linear map $A:V\to V$ and its adjoint map $A^*$
(then $\langle Ax|y\rangle = \langle x|A^*y\rangle$ for any $x,y\in V$).

Now we want to prove that $\operatorname{Im} A^{*} = (\operatorname{Ker}A)^{\perp}$, that is, the image of the adjoint map is the orthogonal complement to the kernel of $A$. And the same about $\operatorname{Ker}A^* = (\operatorname{Im}A)^{\perp}$.

My attempt:
Let's say $(\operatorname{Ker}A)^{\perp} = \{x \in V |\langle x|u\rangle = 0\:\forall u\in\operatorname{Ker}A \}$. 
Now $\operatorname{Im}A^* = \{y\in V | \exists x\in V : A^*x = y \}$. Now consider $\langle A^{*}x|y\rangle$ for all $x\in (\operatorname{Ker}A)^{\perp}, y\in\operatorname{Ker}A$. This dot product equals $\langle x|Ay\rangle = \langle x|0\rangle = 0$. So all $x$ are also mapped into $(\operatorname{Ker}A)^\perp$. So $\operatorname{Im}A^{*} = (\operatorname{Ker}A)^\perp$.

Is it correct?

Answer (score 1):

I'd say you are close to it: When considering $\langle A^{*}x|y\rangle$ then $x$ should run through all of $V$, instead of being restricted to $(\operatorname{Ker}A)^\perp$.

A reformulation of yours: 
Consider some $y\in V$ such that $\,\langle A^*x|y\rangle = 0\:\forall x\in V.\,$

1. What does this imply for $y$?
2. What does it mean for $\,y\,$ if $\,0=\langle x|Ay\rangle\,$
   holds for all $x\in V\,$?

Note that $\exists$ equivalent post [Kernel of adjoint and orthogonal complement images](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/1060163/316749) .

---

**Added in edit:** Found 4 older posts, sorted by age:

1. [Geometric intuition of adjoint](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/472761/316749)
2. [Is the formula $(\text{ker }A)^\perp=\text{im }A^T$ necessarily true?](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/1205388/316749)
3. [$\operatorname{Im} A = (\operatorname{ker} A^*)^\perp$](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/1419137/316749)
4. [image of adjoint equals orthogonal complement of kernel](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/1747559/316749)

Questions 2 through 4 have have got an accepted answer.

Comment: Orthogonal complement holds for all $y \in V$. So I could pick special vectors.

Comment: About second : $y \in KerA$?

Comment: @openspace Yes, $y\in\operatorname{Ker}A$. What do you mean by "Orthogonal complement holds for all $y\in V$." in the other comment?

Comment: $\{ x \in V | \langle x|y \rangle = 0 , \forall y \in U\}$