# Prove Ker$T=($Im$T^*)^\bot$ and (Ker$T^*$)$^\bot$ = Im$T$. Deduce $\dim$Im$T=\dim$Im$T^*$.

Tags: linear-algebra, solution-verification, linear-transformations, inner-products, dimension-theory-analysis

> Let $V$ be a finite dimensional inner product space and $T:V\to V.$
>
> - Prove Ker$T=($Im($T^*))^\bot$ and $($Ker$T^*)^\bot$ = Im$T$.
> - Deduce dimIm$T$ = dimIm$T^*$.

I have written a proof but I'm very unsure about some of the steps and would love another set of eyes:

Let's prove this by using two-sided containment.

First notice, if $KerT =\{0\}$ we have $ImT=ImT^* = V$ and therefore since
$V = ImT^* \oplus (ImT^*)^\bot$, we have $(ImT^*)^\bot=\{0\}.$

Thus meaning we can assume we have $0 \neq v \in KerT$.

Using inner product we can receive 0 = $<T(v),v>$ = $<v,T^*(v)>$ thus implementing since $v \neq 0$ that $T^*(v) = 0$ and so $v \in KerT^*$.

We have $V = KerT^* \oplus (KerT^*)^\bot$ thus this means $v \in KerT^* \to v \notin (KerT^*)^\bot$.

This means we have $v \in (ImT^*)^\bot$ and therfore we have $KerT \subseteq (ImT^*)^\bot$.

For the other side, consider $0 \neq v \in (ImT^*)^\bot$, (which exists from the same reasons as the previous containment).

Since $V = ImT^* \oplus (ImT^*)^\bot$ we have $v \notin ImT^*$ and since $v \neq 0$ we have $v \in KerT^*$.

This implements we have $(ImT^*)^\bot \subseteq KerT$ and so we have $KerT = (ImT^*)^\bot$.

Then we have $ImT = (ImT^*)^* = (((ImT^*)^\bot)^\bot)^* = ((KerT)^\bot)^* = (KerT^*)^\bot$.

By dimension theoreom we have:
$dimV = dimImT + dimKerT = dimImT^* + dimKerT^*$

Since $<T(v),v>$ = $<v,T^*(v)>$ = 0 $\to$ $T(v) = T^*(v) = 0$,
$\forall v \in KerT$ or $v \in KerT^*$ that satsifies $v \neq 0$

then we have $kerT = KerT^*$ thus implamenting $dimKerT = dimKerT^*$.

So we have $dimImT = dimImT^*$, as needed.

Comment: $<v,T^*(v)>=0$ and $v \neq 0$ does not imply $T^*(v) = 0$

Comment: @AnneBauval It was a typo. Regarding your second comment, if the inner product is 0 then we must have $T^*(v) = 0$ or $T^*(v) \bot v$ at least that is what i was thinking

Comment: 1) "and therefore since
$V = ImT^* \oplus (ImT^*)^\bot$, we have $(ImT^*)^\bot=\{0\}$" can be replaced with "and therefore $(ImT^*)^\bot=V^\perp=\{0\}$". 2) $<v,T^*(v)>=0\iff T^*(v)\perp v$ by definition of $\perp$ but your claim that $T^*(v)=0$ is wrong.

Comment: @AnneBauval yes i understand. Would it be alright to claim: $T^*(v)$ $\bot$ $v$ implements $v \notin (KerT^*)^\bot$ ? because that would allow the rest of the proof.

Comment: That is false too.

Comment: @AnneBauval then how can i deduce the correct answer?

Comment: " that would allow the rest of the proof": I don't think so. "$v \notin (KerT^*)^\bot$. This means we have $v \in (ImT^*)^\bot$" is wrong as well. I did not read the rest.

Comment: @AnneBauval thank you very much. Maybe if you could sketch an idea it would be of great help.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Proof of "$\operatorname{Im}A^*$ equals orthogonal complement of $\operatorname{Ker}A$"](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2234174/proof-of-operatornameima-equals-orthogonal-complement-of-operatorname)

Comment: @AnneBauval yes seems like it. Is it possible to assume: $ImT = (KerT^*)^\bot \iff KerT = (ImT^*)^\bot$ ?

Comment: You cannot not *assume* they are *equivalent*. You must *prove each* of them. You can use one of them once proved  (for every $T$) to deduce the other one.

Comment: @AnneBauval Ok thank you very much.